# How does this method of encrypting web addresses work?

Tags: javascript

May I know how it works, the encryption method, and how to replace the URL with my URL. Thank you.

I just learned js. At present, I'm far from understanding these codes. What I want to know is how to replace his website with my website, for example, my domain name is google.com

Thank you.

```
<script>
  var _ = 'https://google.com';
  uu = '11041116111611121115105810471047104810501057110311001104104611191106109811171114110811011121104610991111110910471035';
  var u = [];
  for (var j = 4; j <= uu.length; j += 4) {
   u.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(uu.toString().substr(j - 4, 4)) - 1000));
  }

  _ = u.join('');
  function openUrl1(){
   window.open(_);

  }
  
  </script>
  <script>
  var _2 = 'https://google.com';
  uu2 = '1104111611161112111510581047104711191119111910461104111110981111110711011110111010971110111011211099111111091112109711101121104610991111110910471035';
  var u2 = [];
  for (var j = 4; j <= uu2.length; j += 4) {
   u2.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(uu2.toString().substr(j - 4, 4)) - 1000));
  }

  _2 = u2.join('');
  function openUrl2(){
   window.open(_2);

  }
`your text`
</script>
```

Can't understander these codes, I am a newbie.........

Comment: It's not an encryption (since there is no key) but just obfuscation. And it seems pretty obvious what it does, what in particular do you not understand about the code? Did you step through it with a debugger?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "encryption" is not really worth its name. You should rather call it obfuscation. It is just a "formatting nuissance" and no more. Here are the individual steps to turn the long numeric obfuscated string `uu` into its generating sequence:

```js
const uus = ['11041116111611121115105810471047104810501057110311001104104611191106109811171114110811011121104610991111110910471035',
  '1104111611161112111510581047104711191119111910461104111110981111110711011110111010971110111011211099111111091112109711101121104610991111110910471035'
];

uus.forEach(uu => {
  // divide the string into chunks of 4:
  const u4 = [...Array(uu.length / 4)].map((e, i) => uu.substr(4 * i, 4));
  console.log(u4.join("\n")) // show all 4-character codes

  // subtract 1000 from each code and translate into the corresponding UTF character:
  const carr = u4.map(c => String.fromCharCode(c - 1000));
  console.log(carr.join("")); // join the characters
})
```